# R freeze with table extraction

Tags: r

I have a strange problem with R (on Linux) that I cannot resolve in spite of hours of tries...
My File1 is formated like :

```
Name    Chr     Position        18-B00G44L.CEL.Log_R_Ratio      18-B00G44L.CEL.B_Allele_Freq
SNP_A-2131660   1       1145994 0.0315  0.9700
SNP_A-1967418   1       2224111 0.2447  0.9894
SNP_A-1969580   1       2319424 -0.1340 0.7163
SNP_A-4263484   1       2543484 0.5695  0.8937
SNP_A-1978185   1       2926730 -0.3612 0.1438
SNP_A-4264431   1       2941694 -0.0140 0.0251
SNP_A-1980898   1       3084986 0.0082  0.9900
SNP_A-1983139   1       3155127 0.7095  0.1457
SNP_A-4265735   1       3292731 1.8722  0.5030
```

My File2 is formatted like :

```
            chr     pos
SNP_A-8531044   1       990417
SNP_A-8530320   1       990517
SNP_A-8572481   1       990839
SNP_A-2116190   1       1003629
SNP_A-8325638   1       1017216
SNP_A-8469070   1       1018704
```

I read both files in R with `read.table(File, header = T, row.names=1)`

Now, I do for example :

```
Test = File1[rownames(File2),4,drop=F]
```

And it works fine !

The problem is when I create a third file, with a program originally created for Windows.
The format of File3 is exactly the same as File1 but when I want to run

```
Test = File3[rownames(File2),4,drop=F]
```

Nothing happens... No error message, nothing but R is freezed, like working but I cannot stop it.

I found in File3 hidden characters with `cat -et File3` 
and removed them with `cat File3 | tr -d '\b\r' > New_File3`

But it doesn't change anything.
And now I am lost and confused...

EDIT:
What is strange is that

```
Test = File3["SNP_A-8325638",4,drop=F]
```

or

```
Test = File3[c("SNP_A-8325638","SNP_A-4264431","SNP_A-1983139"),4,drop=F]
```

works fine...

EDIT2:

```
Test = File3[rownames(File2)[26],4,drop=F]
```

also works...

Does someone have an idea, please?

Comment: Have you checked the data.frame using `head(File3)` and `str(File3)`? How big are `File2` and `File3`? If they are huge data.frame subsetting can be slow.

Comment: It's odd that your file1 example doesn't look like it has `rownames()` set. It has a header for the first column `Name` and normally that doesn't appear for `rownames`. You didn't notice any other problems with File3 after you read it in? It had the number of lines you expected?

Comment: File1 has 1.848.112 lines and File3 has 1.754.310 lines, so it has less lines as expected, but I guess it's for the correction program I used and that maybe removed some lines. File2 has 1.838.128 lines. I don't think it's for the size because for File1, Test is generated in few seconds and File3 is smaller...

Comment: @Roland: I tried str(File1) and str(File3) and something is different!
File1:
<pre> $ Chr                          : Factor w/ 24 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...<code>
File3:
$ Chr                         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
Whereas in File2:
 $ chr: Factor w/ 23 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
So I guess the problem comes from the type of variable Chr in File3!
I just have to find a way to change its type...
Do you how to do this?

Comment: Check for strings in a column that should be numeric/integer. Then use the `na.strings` argument of `read.table`. Also, with that many rows you would profit from using package data.table and its faster joins.

Comment: Well, I used File2$Chr<-as.integer(as.character(File2$Chr)) to change the type of Chr in File2 and have same type as File3, it worked, but R still freeze when doing
    Test = File3[rownames(File2),4,drop=F]
so the problem comes from other part...

Comment: @Roland : I do not understand the use of na.strings here. I don't want to lose data replacing it by NAs.

Comment: I can only reiterate: Use data.table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

As I realized that file sizes were like File3 < File2 < File1, I finally wondered if the size could not be an important parameter.

I thus reduce the size (number of lines) of File2 as File2 < File3, removing information I did not used.

And it finally worked.

In conclusion, to do :

```
Test = File3[rownames(File2),4,drop=F]
```

it seems important that the size of File2 is smaller than the size of File3...